# Visual Studio (2010) Mouse wheel sometimes zooms instead of scrolls

Tags: visual-studio-2010, zooming, vertical-scrolling

I don't know what happens, but every once in a while, when I want to scroll down with the mouse wheel, the IDE zooms instead of scrolls.  Other than closing and re-opening Visual Studio, how can I switch back the functionality to make scroll instead of zoom.  (I'm NOT holding down the CNTL key.)

Comment: Be sure not to press the ALT-key when scrolling.

Comment: I'm not - unless the keyboard is stuck.

Comment: It just happened to me on VS2015 during debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing Ctrl Shift - it works in VS 2015.